# linking external javascript in laravel not working

Tags: javascript, laravel

Does the way you add an external **js** link to a laravel application differs to how you add a **css**. I ask because I’ve been able to successfully add a css external file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}"/>
```

When i do this however :

```
<script src="{{asset('js/autocomplete1.js')}}"></script>
```

On the console i get a 404 error that:

```
GET http://spanibox.com/%7B%7B%20route('searchajax')%20%7D%7D?term=a&type=EmpService 404 (Not Found)
```

2 things to consider when you try to answer:

1. This works if i simply write up the javascript within my blade view

2.Not sure if this will be relevant but On firefox there us a warning:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

Comment: take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551787/content-security-policy-including-a-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you are trying to use blade syntax within your JS file. 
In your URL you have this `{{ route('searchajax') }}` which is a blade syntax and JS does not know how to evaluate it.

You can create a global object that will hold your routes or translations. In your main blade file, in the head you can add this:

```
<script>

    window.MY_PROJECT = {
        search_ajax: "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
    };

</script>
```

Then in your JS file use it like this:

```
MY_PROJECT.search_ajax // prints out your URL
```

Comment: This worked thank you very much, without the semi colons of course

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<script src="{{asset('js/autocomplete1.js')}}"></script>` just before your `</body>`. (Note: This may not work depending on what your script is doing.)